# How to export to Excel two dataframes merged

Tags: python

I already know how to export a single dataframe, but now I merged two dataframes by column, and I'd like to export the result on excel, but I don't know exactly how i can do it

This is my full code:

```
from typing import Generator
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import islice


matchlink = "https://www.betexplorer.com/football/colombia/primera-b/results/"


def _get_rows(url: str) -> Generator[dict[str, str], None, None]:
    session = HTMLSession()

    r = session.get(matchlink)

    allmatch = r.html.find(".in-match")
    results = r.html.find(".h-text-center a")
    # search for elements containing "data-odd" attribute
    matchodds = r.html.find("[data-odd]")

    odds = [matchodd.attrs["data-odd"] for matchodd in matchodds]

    idx = 0
    for match, res in zip(allmatch, results):
        if res.text == "POSTP.":
            continue

        if res.text == "0:3 AWA.":
            continue

        if match.text == "Aiolikos - AEL Larissa":
            continue

        if match.text == "Aiolikos - Makedonikos":
            continue


        print(f"{match.text} Z {res.text} {', '.join(odds[idx:idx+3])}")
        yield {
            "match": match.text,
            "result": res.text,
            "odds": ", ".join(odds[idx : idx + 3]),
            "best_bets": (odds[idx]), "oddtwo": (odds[idx+1]), "oddthree": (odds[idx+2]),
        }

        idx += 3


if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.DataFrame(_get_rows(matchlink))#.set_index("match")
    df[['home','away']] = df['match'].str.split("-",expand=True) 
    df[['scorehome','scoreaway']] = df['result'].str.split(":",expand=True) 
    df = df.astype({'scorehome':'int'})
    df = df.astype({'scoreaway':'int'})
    cols = ['scorehome', 'scoreaway']
    df['campionato'] = "Chi-A"
    df['sum_stats'] = df[cols].sum(axis=1, numeric_only=True)
    df['over05'] = np.where(df['sum_stats']>0, 'OK', 'NO')
    df['over15'] = np.where(df['sum_stats']>1, 'OK', 'NO')
    df['over25'] = np.where(df['sum_stats']>2, 'OK', 'NO')
    df['over35'] = np.where(df['sum_stats']>3, 'OK', 'NO')
    df['over45'] = np.where(df['sum_stats']>4, 'OK', 'NO')
    df['goal'] = np.where((df['scorehome'] >= 1) & 
         (df['scoreaway'] >= 1), 'OK', 'NO')
    df['esito'] = [ '1' if score_home > score_away else '2' if score_home < score_away else 'X' 
               for score_home, score_away in zip(df['scorehome'], df['scoreaway'])]
    
    #df['sum'] = df['scorehome'] + df['scoreaway']
    df['result'] = df['result'].str.replace(':','-')
    colss = ['home', 'away', 'result']
    df['uniquefield'] = df[colss].apply(lambda row: ' '.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)
    df = df[['home','away','scorehome','scoreaway','result','best_bets','oddtwo','oddthree', 'sum_stats', 'over05', 'over15', 'over25', 'over35', 'over45', 'goal', 'esito', 'campionato', 'uniquefield']]
    df = df.sort_values('best_bets')

    print(df)



matchlink2 = 'https://www.betexplorer.com/football/chile/primera-division/results/'

def _get_rows(url: str) -> Generator[dict[str, str], None, None]:
 
    session = HTMLSession()
 
    r = session.get(matchlink2)


    links = r.html.find('a.in-match')

    for link in links:
        match_link = link.attrs['href']


        linked = 'https://www.betexplorer.com' + match_link

        session = HTMLSession()
 
        r = session.get(linked)

        allmatch2 = r.html.find("span.list-breadcrumb__item__in")
        partialresults = r.html.find(".list-details__item__partial")
        finalresults = r.html.find(".list-details__item__score")

        
        
        for match2, partialres, finalres in zip(allmatch2, partialresults, finalresults):
            match2.text
            partialres.text
            finalres.text
            print(match2.text)
            print(partialres.text)
            print(finalres.text)
            yield {
                "match": match2.text,
                "htftresult": partialres.text,
                "result": finalres.text,
                
            }

            
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(_get_rows(matchlink2))#.set_index("match")
    df2[['home','away']] = df2['match'].str.split("-",expand=True) 
    df2[['htresult','shresult']] = df2['htftresult'].str.split(",",expand=True) 
    df2['htresult'] = df2['htresult'].str.replace('(','')
    df2['shresult'] = df2['shresult'].str.replace(')','')
    df2['campionato'] = "Chi-A"
    df2['result'] = df2['result'].str.replace(':','-')
    df2['result'] = df2['result']
    colss2 = ['home', 'away', 'result']
    df2['uniquefield2'] = df2[colss2].apply(lambda row: ' '.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)
    df2 = df2[['home','away','htresult','shresult','result','campionato', 'uniquefield2']]

    print(df2)


print(pd.merge(df, df2, left_on='uniquefield', right_on='uniquefield2', how='left').drop('uniquefield2', axis=1))
```

With a single dataframe, at the end of code, I usually used it:

```
    # determining the name of the file
file_name = 'BexData.xlsx'
 
# saving the excel
df.to_excel(file_name)
print('DataFrame is written to Excel File successfully.')
```

but with merged dataframes I don't know exactly, I am a newbie of Python

Thanks for your help

Comment: And why doesn't df.to_excel(file_name) work in this case?

Comment: Hi. You pasted a relatively long snippet of code that appears to include lots of things that are not related to your question. Notably, all these things about fetching and parsing a web url appear to be completely unrelated to the problem of exporting a pandas dataframe to excel. Could you please try to make a [mre] instead?

Comment: @TeemuRisikko because I don't get on excel the second df (df2). How can I get both?

Comment: pass the final merged dataframe independently by `df_merged = pd.merge(df, df2, left_on='uniquefield', ...)` into `.xlsx` **not** only `df`, by `df_merged .to_excel(file_name)` is it still the same output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why the 2 `if __name__ == "__main__":`? Combine your 2 processes into the one `if` statement. Store the merged dataframes, then save it:

```
from typing import Generator
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import islice


matchlink = "https://www.betexplorer.com/football/colombia/primera-b/results/"


def _get_rows(url: str) -> Generator[dict[str, str], None, None]:
    session = HTMLSession()

    r = session.get(matchlink)

    allmatch = r.html.find(".in-match")
    results = r.html.find(".h-text-center a")
    # search for elements containing "data-odd" attribute
    matchodds = r.html.find("[data-odd]")

    odds = [matchodd.attrs["data-odd"] for matchodd in matchodds]

    idx = 0
    for match, res in zip(allmatch, results):
        if res.text == "POSTP.":
            continue

        if res.text == "0:3 AWA.":
            continue

        if match.text == "Aiolikos - AEL Larissa":
            continue

        if match.text == "Aiolikos - Makedonikos":
            continue


        print(f"{match.text} Z {res.text} {', '.join(odds[idx:idx+3])}")
        yield {
            "match": match.text,
            "result": res.text,
            "odds": ", ".join(odds[idx : idx + 3]),
            "best_bets": (odds[idx]), "oddtwo": (odds[idx+1]), "oddthree": (odds[idx+2]),
        }

        idx += 3



matchlink2 = 'https://www.betexplorer.com/football/chile/primera-division/results/'

def _get_rows(url: str) -> Generator[dict[str, str], None, None]:
 
    session = HTMLSession()
 
    r = session.get(matchlink2)


    links = r.html.find('a.in-match')

    for link in links:
        match_link = link.attrs['href']


        linked = 'https://www.betexplorer.com' + match_link

        session = HTMLSession()
 
        r = session.get(linked)

        allmatch2 = r.html.find("span.list-breadcrumb__item__in")
        partialresults = r.html.find(".list-details__item__partial")
        finalresults = r.html.find(".list-details__item__score")

        
        
        for match2, partialres, finalres in zip(allmatch2, partialresults, finalresults):
            match2.text
            partialres.text
            finalres.text
            print(match2.text)
            print(partialres.text)
            print(finalres.text)
            yield {
                "match": match2.text,
                "htftresult": partialres.text,
                "result": finalres.text,
                
            }

            
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.DataFrame(_get_rows(matchlink))#.set_index("match")
    df[['home','away']] = df['match'].str.split("-",expand=True) 
    df[['scorehome','scoreaway']] = df['result'].str.split(":",expand=True) 
    df = df.astype({'scorehome':'int'})
    df = df.astype({'scoreaway':'int'})
    cols = ['scorehome', 'scoreaway']
    df['campionato'] = "Chi-A"
    df['sum_stats'] = df[cols].sum(axis=1, numeric_only=True)
    df['over05'] = np.where(df['sum_stats']>0, 'OK', 'NO')
    df['over15'] = np.where(df['sum_stats']>1, 'OK', 'NO')
    df['over25'] = np.where(df['sum_stats']>2, 'OK', 'NO')
    df['over35'] = np.where(df['sum_stats']>3, 'OK', 'NO')
    df['over45'] = np.where(df['sum_stats']>4, 'OK', 'NO')
    df['goal'] = np.where((df['scorehome'] >= 1) & 
         (df['scoreaway'] >= 1), 'OK', 'NO')
    df['esito'] = [ '1' if score_home > score_away else '2' if score_home < score_away else 'X' 
               for score_home, score_away in zip(df['scorehome'], df['scoreaway'])]
    
    #df['sum'] = df['scorehome'] + df['scoreaway']
    df['result'] = df['result'].str.replace(':','-')
    colss = ['home', 'away', 'result']
    df['uniquefield'] = df[colss].apply(lambda row: ' '.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)
    df = df[['home','away','scorehome','scoreaway','result','best_bets','oddtwo','oddthree', 'sum_stats', 'over05', 'over15', 'over25', 'over35', 'over45', 'goal', 'esito', 'campionato', 'uniquefield']]
    df = df.sort_values('best_bets')

    print(df)


    df2 = pd.DataFrame(_get_rows(matchlink2))#.set_index("match")
    df2[['home','away']] = df2['match'].str.split("-",expand=True) 
    df2[['htresult','shresult']] = df2['htftresult'].str.split(",",expand=True) 
    df2['htresult'] = df2['htresult'].str.replace('(','')
    df2['shresult'] = df2['shresult'].str.replace(')','')
    df2['campionato'] = "Chi-A"
    df2['result'] = df2['result'].str.replace(':','-')
    df2['result'] = df2['result']
    colss2 = ['home', 'away', 'result']
    df2['uniquefield2'] = df2[colss2].apply(lambda row: ' '.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)
    df2 = df2[['home','away','htresult','shresult','result','campionato', 'uniquefield2']]

    print(df2)


    df_merged = pd.merge(df, df2, left_on='uniquefield', right_on='uniquefield2', how='left').drop('uniquefield2', axis=1)

    file_name = 'BexData.xlsx'
     
    # saving the excel
    df_merged.to_excel(file_name)
    print('DataFrame is written to Excel File successfully.')
```